# Java Loop number pattern

Tags: java, for-loop

how do I do a for loop statement for the output to be like (ii) 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 ? I just can't seem to get the correct answer for that output.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: a tiny hint, two nested loops will do the trick :), though that´s not a question fitting SO as it´s basicly a code request

Comment: Count up and for each number `n` print it `n + 1` times. Not too difficult at all.

Comment: Right...and what were you doing to realise that you don't have the correct answer?

Comment: i tried doing nested loop but it seems i am still not getting it public class hello{

     public static void main(String []args){
        for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
            
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
                
                System.out.print(j + " ");
                
            }
            
            
        }
     }
}

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

As you´ve gotten code now here are your mistakes:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
    // You´re printing 0 once, so in order to loop you have to loop until j<=i
    for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
        // You actually did want to print i here, as it will increment.
        // like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. in Order to achive your pattern.
        // When printing j it will allways start with 0 again, as it´s the nested loop
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

The output seems correct now

```
0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: i have got the correct answer. Your code has a small mistake please change your operator from j=<i to j<=i. i have already helped you to change it :)

Comment: @ASHWIIN whups my bad there

Answer (score 0):

To write **a** for loop statement for the output `0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4` you need to use the [A002024](http://oeis.org/A002024) sequence from the OEIS:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    System.out.print(((int) Math.floor((1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * i)) / 2) - 1) + " ");
}
```

You can test it [here](https://ideone.com/ceTvlY).